# Django migrations: create a partial index and set `db_index=True` without creating a full index?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm adding a NULL column to a large table, and I'd like to make sure that it has `db_index=True` set in the model definition:

```
class MyLargeModel(Model):
    new_field = IntegerField(null=True, default=None, db_index=True)
```

But for the actual index I'd like to use a partial index:

```
migrations.RunSQL("""
    CREATE INDEX my_index
    ON mylargemodel (new_field)
    WHERE new_field IS NOT NULL
""")
```

However, by default, this will mean Django's migrations will create an index (which will be very slow), then I'll need to manually drop that index and create my own.

How can I create a migration which will tell Django Migrations that `db_index=True` is set without creating the index in the database?

Comment: Why do you need to set `db_index=True` when you create your own index?

Comment: I'd like to keep `db_index=True` so that future developers (and future me) will know it's indexed and won't need to dig around to wonder what's going on. I know I could add a comment… but I'd rather have the explicit attribute.

Comment: You might find the [class based indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/#class-based-model-indexes) feature useful in the upcoming Django 1.11.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add `new_field` to `MyLargeModel` without `db_index=True` and save
2. run `makemigrations` to generate a migration that will add `new_field` without the index.
3. Update `new_field` in the `MyLargeModel` definition and add back `db_index=True`
4. run `makemigrations` to generate the standard migration to add the index to `MyLargeModel.new_field`
5. Update the migration from (4) by adding the following custom class to the top of the file:

   ```
   from django.db import migrations, models

   class NoopAlterField(migrations.AlterField):
       def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
           pass
   ```
6. Update the migration from (4) by changing the call from `migration.AlterField` to our custom `NoopAlterField`

   ```
   operations = [
       NoopAlterField(
           model_name='mylargemodel',
           name='new_field',
           field=models.IntegerField(...),
       ),
   ]
   ```

---

As you can guess all that this does is creates a `NoopAlterField` migration handler that will update the internal schema tracker but
forego the actual database step of creating the index.